# Install support for ribbon window in Visual studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, ribbon

I have a licensed version of Visual studo 2010 on a Windows 7 machine and want to make an 
ordinary stand alone windows application with the "ribbon window" look and feel in C#.

But I seems not to be able to create a new project "WPF window ribbon style", 
there is no such option (ribbon style) when I am about to create a new project 
nor does all those different downloads I have done from msn helped.
(http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11877)

There is no "ribbon stuff" among the "All WPF Controls" either.

Is it wrong to assume that the "ribbon style" should appear as an option when you create a 
new project, is it something I have to manually add in the xaml file for the main window or 
is there a magic download link that fix everything which I have not discovered ?

I even tried to download "Visual studio 2010 proffesional trial version on another computer 
but that one did not contain the ribbon thing either.

I have tried to download the "SimpleRibbon" project but Visual studio wants to "convert" it 
and then when I try to compile it, it says "error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the WPF Toolkit. The ribbon control is included in there: http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview&ProjectName=wpf. Also: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11877.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your answear, I found out that I was missing the .dll file, got it via the 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/office/aa973809.aspx
(had to accept license agreement as well)

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to read this article and follow the links in the lower part to download the supported and free Microsoft WPF Ribbon control:

[Ribbon (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx)